# Pattern that offers mutual exclusion, re-entrancy, distributed locking towards one (of many) APIs with HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient, mutual-exclusion, reentrantlock

I'm looking for an approach to locking that, by default, makes sure that all calls to a single API are run mutually exclusive using distributed locking. However, at the same time I need the option to instead lock larger blocks of code (critical procedures) containing several calls to that API. Those calls should still be run mutually exclusive. In those cases the approach should be re-entrant, so that each call isn't blocked because the block of code it is in already holds the lock. It should also support re-entrancy if there are several methods nested that lock sections of code.

Examples of use:

```cs
// Should have lock registered by default (f.ex. in HttpMessageHandler)
await _deviceClient.PerformAction();
```

```cs
async Task CriticalProcedure()
{
   // Should only use one lock that is reused in nested code (re-entrant)
   await using (await _reentrantLockProvider.AcquireLockAsync())
   {
      await _deviceClient.TriggerAction();
      await SharedCriticalProcedure();
   }
   // Should only dispose lock at this point
}

async Task SharedCriticalProcedure()
{
   await using (await _customLockProvider.AcquireLockAsync())
   {
      await _deviceClient.HardReset();
      await _deviceClient.Refresh();
   }
}
```

```cs
// Should be forced to run sequentially even though they are not awaited (mutex)
var task1 = _deviceClient.PerformAction1();
var task2 = _deviceClient.PerformAction2();
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
```

Background:

My team is working on a WebAPI that is responsible for making calls to hardware devices. When an endpoint in our API is called, we get a header that identifies the hardware device in question, used in startup to configure the baseUrl of our HttpClients, and we make one or more calls to that API. We have the following limitations:

- A device shouldn't be called when it is already busy with a request (mutual exclusion)
- Some procedures against the device (blocks of code containing several calls) are critical and shouldn't be interrupted by other calls to the device (why I want re-entry)
- A user may run multiple requests to our API simultaneously, so the locking should work across requests
- Our WebAPI may have multiple deployments, so the locking should be distributed
- We use Refit to describe the API of our hardware devices and create HttpClients

I have created the following solution which I believe works. However, it seems clumsy and overengineered, mostly because HttpMessageHandlers have unpredictable lifetimes, not scoped to request, so I needed to use `TraceIdentifier` and a dictionary to enable re-entry during the request lifecycle.

```cs
// In startup
service.AddSingleton<IReentrantLockProvider, ReentrantLockProvider>();

services.
   .AddHttpClient(IDeviceClient)
   .AddTypedClient(client => RestService.For<IDeviceClient>(client, refitSettings))
   .ConfigureHttpClient((provider, client) => ConfigureHardwareBaseUrl())
   .AddHttpMessageHandler<HardwareMutexMessageHandler>();
```

```cs
public class HardwareMutexMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
   private readonly IReentrantLockProvider _reentrantPanelLockProvider;
   private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
   private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> _locks;

   public HardwareMutexMessageHandler(IReentrantLockProvider reentrantPanelLockProvider, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
   {
      _reentrantPanelLockProvider = reentrantPanelLockProvider;
      _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
   }

   protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
      await using (await _reentrantPanelLockProvider.AcquireLockAsync(cancellationToken))
      {
         var hardwareId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["HardwareId"];

         var mutex = _locks.GetOrAdd(hardwareId, _ => new());

         // This is only used to handle cases where developer chooses to batch calls or forgets to await a call
         lock (mutex)
         {
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).Result;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

```cs
public class ReentrantLockProvider : IReentrantLockProvider
{
   private readonly IDistributedLockProvider _distributedLockProvider;
   private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
   private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ReferenceCountedDisposable> _lockDictionary;
   private readonly object _lockVar = new();

   public ReentrantLockProvider(IDistributedLockProvider distributedLockProvider, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
   {
      _distributedLockProvider = distributedLockProvider;
      _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
      _lockDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ReferenceCountedDisposable>();
   }

   public async Task<IAsyncDisposable> AcquireLockAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
   {
      var hardwareId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["HardwareId"];
      var requestId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;

      lock (_lockVar)
      {
         if (_lockDictionary.TryGetValue(requestContext.CorrelationId, out referenceCountedLock))
         {
            referenceCountedLock.RegisterReference();
            return referenceCountedLock;
         }

         acquireLockTask = _distributedLockProvider.AcquireLockAsync(hardwareId, timeout: null, cancellationToken);
            
         referenceCountedLock = new ReferenceCountedDisposable(async () =>
            await RemoveLock(acquireLockTask.Result, requestContext.CorrelationId)
         );

         _lockDictionary.TryAdd(requestContext.CorrelationId, referenceCountedLock);
      }
   }

   private async Task RemoveLock(IDistributedSynchronizationHandle acquiredLock, string correlationId)
   {
      ValueTask disposeAsyncTask;

      lock (_lockVar)
      {
         disposeAsyncTask = acquiredLock.DisposeAsync();
         _ = _lockDictionary.TryRemove(correlationId, out _);
      }
        
      await disposeAsyncTask;
   }
}
```

```cs
public class ReferenceCountedDisposable : IAsyncDisposable
{
   private readonly Func<Task> _asyncDispose;
   private int _refCount;

   public ReferenceCountedDisposable(Func<Task> asyncDispose)
   {
      _asyncDispose = asyncDispose;
      _refCount = 1;
   }

   public void RegisterReference()
   {
      Interlocked.Increment(ref _refCount);
   }

   public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
   {
      var references = Interlocked.Decrement(ref _refCount);

      if (references == 0)
      {
         await _asyncDispose();
      }
      else if (references < 0)
      {
         throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't dispose multiple times");
      }
      else
      {
         GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Explain the actual problem, not how you think it can be solved. If you want to ensure that only one request is made to each hardware device at a time, a "distributed lock" isn't the solution. Perhaps you need a single worker per device. Perhaps that worker will need a queue with requests. If you need to coordinate clients and devices you may need a proper queue broker like RabbitMQ or ZeroMQ

Comment: For worker implementations .NET has the high-level Dataflow classes that can be used to construct pipelines of processing blocks, similar to a shell or CSP pipeline. The blocks handle their own buffering and execution, working on one message at a time by default. They also preserve input and output order. These classes grew out of the MS Robotics framework. For lower level implementations, the Channel class is an asynchronous queue that preserves message order.

Comment: You're right! I got a bit lost in my approach. I could potentially break it down into two solutions, one for locking blocks of code and one for making sure all calls are run sequentially (using one of your suggestions). Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: You don't need to lock blocks of code when you have `async/await` and dataflow blocks. An [ActionBlock or TransformBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-perform-action-when-a-dataflow-block-receives-data) uses a single worker task by default, which means that code executes sequentially - in the background, but sequentially. You can increase the number of worker tasks if needed *BUT* a TransformBlock guarantees both the input and output order, which means in/out messages remain in sequence

Comment: Yes, I was trying to safe-guard against developers not using await. However, that's probably overdoing it. The worst that can happen is for the hardware to act up as a result of developer error. An ActionBlock can't work across multiple deployments, right? That's why I initially went with DistributedLock.